# what Linux Command can merge this format?

Tags: linux, shell

if i have one file containing two columns delimited by a tab:

```
Good  A
Bad   B
...
```

And another file contains one column only:

```
This is A.
This is B.
```

What Linux command can merge the two files together, putting each line from the first file at the beginning of each line from second file:

```
Good  A   This is A.
Bad   B   This is B.
```

Thanks for your help. I work with Windows everyday, and don't want to write a Java program to do this.
...

Comment: Thanks for the formatting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [paste](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/), it will do exactly that

```
paste file1 file2
```

Comment: Great. I will try. I even don't know 'paste' is a linux command. Good to know.